# Прокрутка страницы к верху при клике на объект

Tags: jquery, javascript

Ситуация: **google custom search** - при клике перехода на следующую страницу в результатх поиска страница прокручивается вверх не до конца (баг у гугла наверно), пытаюсь сделать сам с помощью jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".gsc-cursor-page").click(function () {
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
});

});
```

**.gsc-cursor-page** - див, в котором находится постраничная навигация, конкретно цифра страницы.

но оно напрочь не хочет делать прокрутку при таком раскладе, возможно потому, что у гугла есть своя задача при клике на этот див, и напрочь игнорится моя задача. При этом если вешать событие на клик любого другого элемента (тоже дива), то все отлично работает.

Пациент [тут](http://buoz.ru/res.php?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)

Comment: видимо чуда не будет.. как всегда ^_^

Comment: а если попытаться в ``.animate()`` передать колбек, который быдет повторно делать ту же анимацию?

Comment: а на пальцах можно? я не силен в js..

Comment: как-то так:
   
    $(".gsc-cursor-page").click(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast', function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0};});
    });

Comment: неа, не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
```

попробуйте поменять селекторы. Например:

```
$('body') 
или
$('html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял: есть некий `div`, который содержит номера страниц. Это ссылки, при нажатии на которых страница должна прокручиваться наверх. Этот `div` имеет класс `.gsc-cursor-page`. Ошибка в том, на мой взгляд, что должно отслеживаться событие нажатия на ссылку внутри этого дива, а не на сам `div`, как это у вас. 
Приблизительно вот так:

`$('div.gsc-cursor-page a').click(function....`

Comment: нет, там нет ссылки - тупо див и внутри него текст (номер страницы) если обратите внимание, в самом низу справа есть кнопка "наверх" - так вот там тоже самое: див с текстом внутри, с таким же классом див, и все работает.

Comment: пропишите вместо вызова анимации console.log('click is work'); Далее загляните в консоль и проверьте по клику будет ли появлятся эта надпись в консоле (так проверим срабатывает ли у вас хотя бы клик)